# React Native - `require()` statement exception handling

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, momentjs

**TL;DR:** I want to be able to `require` a module in `react-native` and handle the exception myself in case the module does not exist (instead of displaying the `RedBox`).

---

I am using `moment.js`'s logic to choose the most suitable locale from its library of presets (https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/develop/locale), when given a requested locale.

For example, if asked for `en-us`, and it was not found, it will fall back to `en` and so forth. The code for this logic (`chooseLocale`, `loadLocale`) can be found here: https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/lib/locale/locales.js

Basically, it tries to `require` the given preset. If it does not exist, it gets en exception from the `require` statement, catches it and moves on to the next option.

Now, my issue is trying to use this logic with `react-native`. The `require` statement is actually implemented with `react-native`'s `guardedLoadModule` which handles the exception (displays red screen). In my opinion, `moment`'s logic is not hurt by this logic, hence I would like for the `RedBox` to not display.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible ([link to discussion](https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/120)):

> Optional dependency is released in metro 0.59

Simply surround your code with `try` `catch`:

```
let module;
try {
  module = require('module');
} catch {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

React-native's `require` is different from node.js's `require` in the sense that the app is bundled and packaged before the application runs. As a consequence it is not possible to perform dynamic `require` statements. See also [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391).

Check the following github issue on react-native, as it includes a "solution" to your problem. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1629

In other words: you will have to implement the fallback mechanism yourself, and explictely tell moment which locale to use.

```
switch deviceLocale:
case 'es':
  require('moment/locale/es');
  break;
case 'he':
  require('moment/locale/he');
  break;
```

Comment: You actually can use `require` dynamically. When I try to load a locale that does exist, it loads perfectly fine. The only issue is when `moment` tries to load a locale that does not exist (and should continue to try to load the next locale in its list).

Comment: I was mistaken, dynamic require statements are indeed not supported in react-native. Apologies @Thomas :-)